# fatal: bad config file line 1 in /home/trx/.gitconfig

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I know this question has been asked a million times, but my ~/.gitconfig consists of only two lines, that are character correct with the tutorial.

```
git config --global user.name "trx"
git config --global user.email chazx@live.com
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is my ~/.gitconfig:

```
[user]
    name = Luigi R. Viggiano
    email = luigi.viggiano@...
[color]
    ui = true
[merge]
    tool = p4merge
[diff]
    tool = p4merge
[push]
    default = simple
```

your `~/.gitconfig` is not in the correct format.

You don't need to put the commands:

```
git config --global user.name "trx"
git config --global user.email chazx@live.com
```

in a file... you need to type them at the terminal.

Delete your `~/.gitconfig` and manipulate it using the `git config` command at the terminal, as explained in the tutorial.

Comment: Doh, that is funny. I figured that these were commands that would be ran when they were read from the file. Thanks so much. (5 minutes to accept)

Answer (score 4):

These `git config` lines are commands that you should run, not the contents for the config file.