# GitHub error "fatal: bad config file line 1 in .git/config" when in git shell

Tags: git, shell, github, config

Im using GitHub on Windows and after working fine for the whole time, when I opened it today, it says:

> Failed to load commit history for this repository. You might need  to
>   open a shell and debug the state of this repo.

And then:

> Failed to get list of branches.

When I open shell and try `git status` or whatever other command, it returns this error :

> fatal: bad config file line 1 in .git/config

Not sure what to do with that? I read someone saying to replace the config file with an earlier version of it, but I dont have an earlier version..

Comment: I hit an identical problem this week with a newly created repo that has only one branch. I fixed it by copying the origin and master sections from the config file of another repo (and editing the one obvious line).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My question might have been abit vague, but I wasnt sure myself what happened. I solved it by finding .git/config file on my laptop using Windows search , and deleting it. Then I deleted content of my github folder and cloned the repo again and it worked after :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876728/fatal-bad-config-file-line-1-in-home-trx-gitconfig

Answer (score 23):

I solved this by

1. open .git/config file
2. clear all the NULL values in the file
3. save and close the file
4. git add .

Comment: This helped me too. I was getting the same error just that n line number 16. I removed the last line which was actually just a whitespace. Saved the file and it worked.

Comment: I had issue in shallow file. I removed all null values and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks to save my project from being lost.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this on my mac by

1. created a .gitconfig file in $HOME(cmd + shift + h) folder
2. added `[user]
   name = myname
   email = myemail@example.com`
    in the .gitconfig file
3. saved and replaced with the existing file

now all git commands started working

Comment: exactly. In my case:  [user]
name = name.surname
email = name.surname@mail.com
[core]
autocrlf = true
[push]
default = simple

Answer (score 3):

I had got same problem and i removed  the .gitconfig file from local repository .The prroblem is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I was with Visual Studio Code and facing the same issue. I went to ".git>config" file and cleared that file, saved it.
[image]

That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

- Open **Terminal** and type `cd $HOME` to navigate to user's home.
- Then type `vim ~/.gitconfig` to navigate to **.gitconfig** file.
- Press **'i'** which gives Insert.
- Make sure the second line in that editor consists only **'[user]'**, if there's any commit name, delete it.
- After changes if any, press **'escape button'** and type **':wq'**.
- After this, you can continue with the regular git setup config methods for name and email.

Answer (score 1):

c:/users/username/.gitconfig

delete .gitconfig file from given location in your pc and then write git init. it would be work properly

Comment: HI mani :) Welcome! Your answer is very similar to the accepted answer and as such will likely be marked as a duplicate. I'd recommend looking at all existing answers on questions such as this, which are years old.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest solution. If the folder files not modified.

You can clone the same git in another folder of same server.

Just try to replace the entire .git folder.

config with below,

*git config user.name "username"

git config user.email "youremail"*

> Note: this only applicable if there is no change in codes also Not
> suggested for live server.

Answer (score -2):

I just deleted all the contents of .gitignore and ran the following commands:

```
git config --global user.name "give your user name here"    
git config --global user.email "your.email.id"
```

note: I had just installed git on my pc so there weren't much changes in .gitignore file so i guess it was safe to clear everything.

Comment: Gitignore has nothing to do with configuration.