# I cannot add the parent directory to *safe.directory* in Git

Tags: git, cve-2022-24765

After updating Git to `v2.35.2.windows.1` I'm getting the following error:

> fatal: unsafe repository ('F:/GitHub/my-project' is owned by someone else) 
> To add an exception for this directory, call: 
>
> git config --global --add safe.directory F:/GitHub/my-project

I've tried adding the parent directory of my projects to `.gitconfig`, but it doesn't work.

```
[safe]
    directory = F:/GitHub/
    directory = F:/Private/
```

- Is there a workaround for this?
- What does it actually mean by "'x' is owned by someone else"?

I don't want to add every single project I'm working on to the `.gitconfig` file.

Comment: In my case, I'm the only one working on my laptop. However, since I clone to root rather than my home directory (don't judge me for that), I received this error because directories that I built at the root using `sudo` belong to the `root` user and not me.

Comment: Also note that the drive letter casing has to match, else this wont work.

Comment: @DrLightman: you can downgrade your git version, and all things work fine. You have the choice between security and simple living (but note: now the security problem is known, so you should regularly check that nobody in your system is abusing it)

Comment: Note: Now there is a `v2.35.3.windows.1` which fixes some problems (the configuration message now is corrected, and so it *fixes* the problem (but still single repository at a time). (previously: it didn's tell you to add `prefix`, and when it complained, it missed one slash (in case of network drive with ip).

Comment: Is this limited to Windows or not?

Comment: Related (more Linux oriented): *[fatal: unsafe repository ('/home/repon' is owned by someone else)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71901632/)*

Comment: FYI, it seem if you are using fat32 or exfat disks this is an issue.  and a very stupid issue at that.

Comment: For the record, the linked CVE https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-24765 contains a description of the problem and why it is a security issue.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Starting in Git v2.35.3, [safe directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.35.2#Documentation/git-config.txt-safedirectory) checks can be disabled, which will end all the "unsafe repository" errors (this will also work in [the latest patch versions of 2.30-34](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=164989570902912&w=2)).

This can be done by running:

`git config --global --add safe.directory '*'`<sup>1</sup>

It will add the following setting to your global `.gitconfig` file:

```
[safe]
    directory = *
```

Before disabling, **make sure you understand this security measure**, and [why it exists](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8959555cee7ec045958f9b6dd62e541affb7e7d9). You **should not do this** if your repositories are stored on a shared drive.

However, if you are the sole user of your machine 100% of the time, *and* your repositories are stored locally, then disabling this check should, theoretically, pose no increased risk.

Also note that you can't currently combine this with a file path, as [the command doesn't interpret the wildcard `*` as an operator](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3809#issuecomment-1102681740) per say– it just takes the `"*"` argument to mean "disable safe repository checks/ consider all repositories as safe".

---

<sup>**1** - If this fails in your particular terminal program in Windows, try surrounding the wildcard with double quotes instead of single (Via [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3809)):

`git config --global --add safe.directory "*"`</sup>

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work.  It does work if I specify a specific directory.  Are you sure this wildcard setting works?

Comment: Yes, tested it. Git v2.35.3 on Win10.

Comment: I too was able to get this to work; I ran it in git bash on Windows. This should, theoretically, not open any security holes if you're the **sole user** on a machine, and if the repositories you use are on **a local drive** (rather than some shared one). In my case, I'm the sole user of my Windows machine, and my repositories are in a directory at the base of `C:` drive.

Comment: @nonrectangular If you're on Windows, you might try using double quotes instead of single around the wildcard `"*"`.

Comment: There must be more going on. It does not work for me on Ubuntu 20.04. It adds the right stuff to .gitconfig but I still get the error.

Comment: Me again, sorry but I thought I had upgraded git on the server I am testing on, but no. After doing that and doing what zcoop98 said, it works fine now! YAY!

Comment: Is there any documentation for use of wildcards in this setting? Instead of just using `*`, I tried using `C:/Users/MyUser/Projects/*`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks @HalBurgiss.  I failed to realize the wildcard is only available in git v2.35.1 and later.  Ubuntu 20.04 ships with v2.25.1.  Ubuntu applied the security patch to the older versions of git, including v2.25.1, so it would produce this new error, but did not patch support for this wildcard solution.  See M.S. Arun's solution to use a PPA on Ubuntu 20.04 to get the latest git.

Comment: @asherber To clarify, via [this post in the GitHub thread](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3809#issuecomment-1102681740), the asterisk here isn't actually used by git as a "wildcard"– just as a symbol to represent "disable safe repo/ consider all repos as safe".

Comment: @zcoop98 Thanks, good catch. And too bad! A wildcard would be useful.

Comment: Yes, they fix a security issue so badly that disabling the security fix is necessary to get work done. Awesome.

Comment: This setting does nothing for me, I still get the same error. Taking ownership of the folder isn't an option either, as the problem occurs on the build server and the build user isn't allowed to own the folder containing the git repository.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in CygWin or plain windows cmdPrompt as "*" or '*'.  It worked in cmdPrompt when i removed all quotes and just did a plain *.  (this didn't work in cygwin)

Comment: Since globs can't be used, is there a way to whitelist a user like `root` (e.g. for my NTFS-mounted drive on Ubuntu)?

Comment: To undo the addition, use this command: `git config --global --unset --fixed-value safe.directory '*'`

Answer (score 100):

#### Answer

This seems to be related to this announcement of a vulnerability:
https://github.blog/2022-04-12-git-security-vulnerability-announced/

I think it has less to do with your email, and more with the owner of the directories on your filesystem.
Is the user you're currently logged in with also the owner of the folder?
How about the parent folder?
Also, are you invoking git from within the repository directory?
The update is only a few hours old, so I guess things are still in flux.

For now, as the message from git suggests, execute

```
git config --global --add safe.directory F:/GitHub/my-project
```

and make sure you are calling `git` from within `F:/GitHub/my-project` for now.

**EDIT**: As we found out in the comments below, the owner of the parent of the directory containing the `.git` folder (the git repository) is the issue.
Cloning the project anew is a platform independent way to make sure you are the owner.

#### Sidenote

I ran into the same problem using flutter on Linux, which on my distro was installed in `/opt/flutter`. I am not working as root, thus I run into the same problem.
Running `git config --global --add safe.directory /opt/flutter` did indeed fix the problem for me.

#### Longer edit: Clarification

Going through the post about the vulnerability again after a good night's sleep, I think a bit of clarification is in order. I'll leave the rest of the answer as is.
Lets look at the following simple directory structure.

```
/home/
├─ tommy/
│  ├─ .git/
│  ├─ rental_space/
│  │  ├─ mary/
│  │  │  ├─ projects/
│  │  │  │  ├─ phone_app/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ .git/
│  │  ├─ anthony/
```

In this case, the user `tommy` owns his own directory under `/home`, but (for some reason) rents out space to other users, in this case `mary` and `anthony`. 
If `mary`, by mistake, where to execute `git` in her directory, but outside of her `phone_app` project, then old `git` would go up the directory tree to search a `.git` repository. The first it finds is the one from `/home/tommy/.git`. This is a security risk, because another user, in this case anyone that can act as `tommy`, can affect `mary`'s execution of git and possibly cause trouble.
From Git v2.35.2 and onward, the traversal will stop as soon as the directory entered belongs to a user other than `mary`. Say `mary` executed `git` in `/home/tommy/rental_space/mary/projects`, then git will check in `projects`, but find no `.git`. It will go up one directory, check in `mary`, but again find no `.git`. Then it will again go up, but `rental_space` belongs to `tommy`, not `mary`. The new git version will stop here and print the message we saw in the question.
Adding the directory `/home/tommy/rental_space` to the `safe.directory` variable would allow git to proceed but is, as explained, a security risk.

I used a Linux-like directory structure here, but the same is true on Windows.

Comment: Yes the current user is the owner of both project and their parent directories. And also yes I'm invoking git from within the repository directory but error still there. Thanks for your answer, I guess I'll add the directories one by one until a fix rolls out.

Comment: Just noticed the `.git` directory has a weird owner possibly from a previous Windows installation. Changing the permission didn't work but cloning the project again didn't raise the "owned by someone else" error. Interesting.

Comment: Mhh that is interesting indeed, and most likely the cause. And this is probably also the reason why this change in git was made, since someone else could conceivably modify your .git folder.
Good to hear that a simple re-clone fixed your problem though!

Comment: Seems that for submodules, the submodule folder and .git file need correct ownership now too. i.e. adding the parent project as a safe.directory will include submodules but only if their file ownership matches current user (or perhaps the parent .git folder).

Comment: Actually, see my answer; seems that adding to safe.directory is not required on Linux at least, if you are the owner of the folder containing the git repo.

Comment: @webaware Can't comment on your answer yet (.....), but I don't think you added much more than a minor clarification. I'll fix up my answer a bit!

Comment: You are correct that the `user.*` settings are irrelevant. The security issue is that on WIndows shared drives (and potentially on any multi-user system including some Linux systems) it may be possible to trick people into running Trojan Horse software. Git tries to use the OS's concept of file-and-directory-ownership to get around this security issue.

Comment: So I am running into this same issue. I am pretty sure that it is because I am running a git command inside of my php code from the browser which runs the command under one user, but the owner of the directory for the repository is a different user. I just don't understand why I am running into this issue if I haven't updated git. I am currently on version 2.25.1. I have also tried adding the safe.directory config variable and it still isn't working.

Comment: @Battousai In the [git post I mentioned](https://github.blog/2022-04-12-git-security-vulnerability-announced/), they discuss how to reduce the risk on older versions by modifying the [`GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES` environment variable](https://git-scm.com/docs/git/2.35.2#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITCEILINGDIRECTORIEScode). Maybe that was done in your case?

Comment: There are other problems with trusting folders on Windows.  The latest Beta of GitHub Desktop fixes the problem. Git also fails to check whether an NTFS folder's owner is a security group that the user might be in.

Comment: *"Adding the directory /home/tommy/rental_space to the safe.directory variable would allow git to proceed but is, as explained, a security risk."*  It's not clear there whether you mean you can do it via `--add safe.directory` but it comes with a risk, or that git will just not do it anyway because of the risk.  It just plain does not work for me: I literally cut n' paste the `--add safe.directory` command (as both the directory owner and the git user), try git again, nothing has changed, v2.35.3 <- What's strangest is that using `safe.directory '*''` *does* work.

Comment: @CodeClown42 Not sure why you think it is unclear, I think that sentence is pretty clear. Add the path to `safe.directory` and git **will** proceed, in spite of the risk.
About the command not working for you, I cannot comment on that without more details - maybe open a new question if you are still facing that issue.

Comment: I think it's potentially unclear because of the difference between your sentence in the comment above and the original source -- they are not the same, and although the latter *could* mean the same thing, it *could* also mean something contradictory.  Admittedly, I don't think I would have harped on it if `--add safe.directory` had worked.  The fact that it didn't would have led me to consider the possibility that, eg., a typo of mine was involved, then when that was ruled out, that I had misunderstood the docs (or online advice) leading me to take note of ambiguities therein.

Comment: @CodeClown42 Frankly I still don't see how that part is unclear, but if you think it could be phrased cleaner then please suggest an edit to my post!

Answer (score 20):

As [@derpda said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71849415/cannot-add-parent-directory-to-safe-directory-on-git/71850261#71850261), it's related to a [Git  security vulnerability](https://github.blog/2022-04-12-git-security-vulnerability-announced/) that has been fixed.

On Linux, at least, you can fix the problem by ensuring that the parent folder of the Git repository is owned by you. There isn't any need to add the `safe.directory` configuration setting if you can set the folder ownership appropriately.

If you need different ownership (e.g., working on a service that runs as a different user), then add your folder to the multi-value `safe.directory` configuration setting:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory /path/to/project
```

Comment: i wish this worked for me... my folder is on my WSL and its obv a different user to my windows system...

Answer (score 19):

I found the same issue on Windows after upgrading to version 2.35.2.windows.1.

I was able to fix it by taking ownership of the folder containing the .git folder and all the files in it.

This is the command assuming you already are in the repository folder:

```
takeown.exe /f . /r
```

Note:  if you have multiple repository folders inside a work folder, you may want to take ownership of the work folder and its subfolders recursively. It takes more time to execute, but you only need to do this once.

The command would look like this under [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe):

```
takeown.exe /f C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Work /r
```

Or like this under [powershell.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) or pwsh.exe:

```
takeown.exe /f $HOME\Work /r
```

Comment: I would not recommend taking ownership recursively. You only need ownership of the parent folder of `.git` and of `.git` itself.
For example, using your suggetsions becomes important when your project includes folders used as docker volumes. The permissions inside those folders are often different on purpose, and have no effect whatsoever on the problem with git.

Comment: @derpda, I generally agree, but your comment is completely true only when you execute all Git commands from the repo's root. If you execute the commands from a subdirectory, the whole path up to the parent of `.git` needs to be owned by the current user.

Comment: @Palec You are right about that, but in the example I gave of a docker volume, changing ownership of the directory is a bad solution - just change directory with `cd` instead so you can safely execute `git`.

Comment: `takeown` also screws multiboot. git needs to do proper ACL checks. Yeah, those things that nobody uses on Linux because they are broken. They work on Windows. Pretty much always have.

Answer (score 8):

For those working on an [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) mounted file system (probably a shared data drive with Windows), you can edit your mount options in `/etc/fstab` by appending `defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000` to it. This is as by default; you can't permanently change the owner of `.git` in NTFS. These options will make everything owned by your current user (rather than by *root*).

Comment: Thank your, works like a charm :D I'm using bitlocker with a windows partition and the owner can acces now to the .git file.

Answer (score 8):

### For (mainly) Visual Studio 2022 users:

**This is my setup:**

- Git version `2.36.0.windows.1`
- Mounted [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) network share from my [NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) `\\MyNas\User` as `X:\`
- The *remote branch* was cloned into a directory on `X:\`.
- My NAS and PC are not in the same [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_controller).
- My IDE: **Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise 17.2.0 Preview 4.0** (latest)

**The issue so far:**

Since my NAS and PC are not in the same domain, I cannot set my PC user as the owner of the NAS directory.

When opening the repository in Visual Studio, this error showed up in the console:

```
Opening Repository:
X:\Repo
Git failed with a fatal error.
fatal: unsafe repository ('//MyNas/User/Repo' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///MyNas/User/Repo'
```

**After long testing:**

The issue was the portable Git installation of Visual Studio, which had the version `2.35.2`. Visual Studio, even when the component "Git for Windows" was unchecked, still used its own Git-installation instead of my global Git installation.

**The** ***solution:***

1. Add the repository directory as a safe directory with the recommended command:

   ```
   git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///MyNAS/User/Repo'

   # Or just trust any directory (not really recommended)
   git config --global --add safe.directory *
   ```
2. Update the Git-Version which Visual Studio uses.
   (I just took the files from the global Git installation located in `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin` and pasted them to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw64\bin`)

**Maybe** an alternative of copy/pasting files, would be to make Visual Studio use the global installation of Git, like described in this Stack Overflow question:
*[Configure Visual Studio to use system-installed Git.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60326277/13182522)*. 
*Note: I have not tested this alternative, since I already overwrote the Git files in my Visual Studio installation directory.*

**Key notes:**

- Latest Git version (2.36.0) supports safe/trusted directories.
- Make sure your IDE is using the latest version of Git.

Comment: Yes. Just point out that `%(prefix)` is _literally_ `%(prefix)` and not some variable substitution.

Answer (score 7):

I had a local repository at my Windows PC mapped to a network folder:

> n:\folder

This points to

> \windows-server\folder\working-folder

When I tried to do

```
n:\folder> git status
```

there came this known error:

> fatal: unsafe repository ('//windows-server/folder/working-folder' is
> owned by someone else) To add an exception for this directory, call:
>
> ```
>     git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///windows-server/folder/working-folder'
> ```

To change file permissions was not possible in my case. So I tried

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///windows-server/folder/working-folder'
```

but this did *not* work. I had to remove the ''!

Solution:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory %(prefix)///windows-server/folder/working-folder
```

Comment: upvoted, thanks - note that wildcards dont seem to work any more

Comment: only * and not "*" works for me too. thanks!

Comment: removing single quotes was it thanks

Comment: it also seems to be case sensitive

Answer (score 7):

On windows, I use this

```
git config --global --add safe.directory *
```

or

```
git config --global --replace-all safe.directory *
```

Comment: While I assume this is not ideal for an actual development environment, this is exactly what I needed to deal with the current insanity that is, in my case, comfyui-manager on a portable hard drive.

Answer (score 6):

## **For Ubuntu 20.xx Users Fix - 2022 UPDATE:**

Updating Git with this PPA provides the latest stable upstream Git version fixed this issue.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa

sudo apt update

sudo apt install git
```

Ref: https://git-scm.com/download/linux

Comment: There is [Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) and [Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.10_(Groovy_Gorilla)). What version, incl. minor version, did you test it on?

Comment: Works for mine on 20.04 according to https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa both should work

Answer (score 6):

It happened to me, because I'd reinstalled my Windows system, and the owner of some repository folders are the old user in the former install. So Git won't let you use those folders directly.

You can check this by *Properties* → *Security* → *Advanced* → *Owner*. If the current owner is something like "S-1-blah-blah", then you encountered the same problem as me.

If you are sure you are the *real owner* of those folders, you can just use the `takeown` command:

```
cd F:/GitHub/
takeown /f *
```

The `/r` switch does not seem to be required for my case.

Comment: I have solved this problem for YEARS by having `BUILTIN\Administrators` as the owner, but now I have been set back a decade because git is using Linux semantics on Windows and they shortcut doing the work with some talk about performance while all they need to check is the repo root. But properly.

Answer (score 6):

In [Termux](https://termux.dev) on Android, you have to add the actual `git` repo, not the parent directory.

```
git config --global --add safe.directory /storage/emulated/0/src/go2null-dotfiles
```

You can also disable the check.

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding this here since it seems no-one else has, and it helped me. You can set this system-wide by running as root with `--system` instead of `--global`, eg:

`sudo git config --system --add safe.directory '*'`

Answer (score 4):

I run Visual Studio sometimes as *Administrator* and sometimes as a normal user. This leads to the problem.

**Symptoms 1**

In Visual Studio - when opening a local folder - it seems as if the code is no longer added to source control.

Opening a solution in [Visual Studio 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2019): The above messages appear in the Git output window for each project.
Opening a solution in [Visual Studio 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2022): It just says `One or more errors occurred.`.

**Symptoms 2**

When opening a normal command prompt in the parent folder of `.git` executing `git log` shows the message

```
fatal: unsafe repository ('C:/GIT/MyProject' is owned by someone else)
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory C:/GIT/MyProject
```

There are no errors when executing any command in an Administrator command prompt.

**Solution**

Change the owner of the MyProject folder to the normal user. Afterwards everything works fine as normal user and also as *Administrator*.

Comment: I've already filed an issue in Visual Studio Community to add a warning about this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Consider-adding-a-warning-for-fatal:-uns/10012582

Answer (score 4):

On [Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) and [Laravel Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/) (user isolation):

I tried updating Git to 2.36 as recommended in previous answers, but this did *not* work. I tried the GitHub solution:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory GIT/MyProject
```

and also as recommended in a previous answer:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```

None of these worked for me.

The only thing that worked was ensuring that the ownership of the parent directory and the project directory where folder *.git* is located has the same owner as [explained by Tc Blaize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71849415/i-cannot-add-the-parent-directory-to-safe-directory-in-git/71856867#71856867).

Comment: True. In my case while parent directory and all sub folders were owned by one user, .git and .gitignore were used by another user. Fixing owner helped

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the same problem, because I had to reinstall windows and copied the repository from the old system's drive.

A look at the security settings of the folders made clear that the "old users" id (the previous windows system) was set. Because the old user is unknown in the new system the dialog only showed the SID of the user.

**Right click on folder -> Properties -> Security -> Advanced**

[image]

After I changed the ownership to my actual user everything works fine again.

[image]

Don't forget to check the **"Replace owner on subcontainers and objects"**. Otherwise only the acutal folder (git repo folder) will have the new ownership.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, on an [Ubuntu 20.04.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) system (Focal Fossa), the project folder had the ownership set to the application user, e.g., ***www-data:www-data***, but the .git folder when initiated had its ownership set to ***root:root***.

To fix this issue, I changed the ownership on my project folder to ***root:root*** so as to match its contents (including the *.git* folder). Then all Git actions started working as normal.

Comment: Do that imply that you run all Git operations as root?

Comment: There must be more going on as this did not work for me.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Not all, I only had to do that for this case and this folder alone.

Answer (score 3):

As a part of automation, *our* scenario involved invoking one script multiple times and we don't know the workspace upfront.

So, in our case, `git config --global --add safe.directory *` created multiple entries in `~/.gitconfig`.

`git config --global --replace-all safe.directory '*'` helped us ensuring no duplicate entries.

Comment: I'm really enjoying in how git was broken for a ton of people just to "protect" a small number of people that can't seem to check their own security in shared environments.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, when you create a folder from an elevated prompt, it gets the owner set to the *Administrators* group.

Then inside it, when you clone the repository using a non-elevated prompt, it gets you as an owner. It is enough to trigger a new Git validation.

Comment: In general, I would recommend against this. It is much safer to be running usually as non-admin.

On windows, we used @marcodor's solution:
`git config --global --add safe.directory *`
and it disabled this check for us (which makes sense for us)

Comment: This answer is not suggesting to run git as admin. It only refers to creating the folder, and likely not as a solution, but that doing so *causes* the issue. At least on my system, I was getting the error because my project directories are owned by the 'Administrators' group.

Answer (score 2):

**For Windows make sure your path is correct case**

In case this helps anyone else. I found that I had used the wrong case for the drive letter. The git command needs to be copied verbatim including case. This means no trailing slash and identical case for every character.

I was using a Git UI client which displayed a message box with the command, so I couldn't copy paste. The first time I added I used Git Bash auto-complete for the file path and this used the wrong case.

I recommend checking the .gitconfig file after running the command to check it was added correctly.

Example:

> fatal: unsafe repository ('F:/GitHub/my-project' is owned by someone
> else) To add an exception for this directory, call:
>
> git config --global --add safe.directory F:/GitHub/my-project

Not correct:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory f:/GitHub/my-project
```

Not correct:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory F:/github/my-project
```

Not correct:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory F:/GitHub/my-project/
```

Correct:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory F:/GitHub/my-project
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Windows 11 and WSL and I was getting this error in Sourcetree. I made two mistakes initially -- running the command from WSL, and using quotes *as Sourcetree suggested*. Once I ran it from cmd at C:\Users\alyssa, and without quotes, it was putting the correct syntax in the correct .gitconfig file:

```
C:\Users\alyssa\.gitconfig:

[safe]
    directory = %(prefix)///wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/alyssa/my-repo
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs after the Ubuntu auto package update. After checking the updates in log file, */var/log/apt/history.log*, I found two Git packages updated and after that update date mess with [Phabricator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phabricator) occurred.

```
git
git-man
```

I used the below two commands to check the previous version in the cache and installed the old version.

```
apt-cache policy git:amd64
```

Output:

```
git:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.10
  Version table:
     1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.10 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     ***1:2.17.0-1ubuntu1*** 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

---

```
sudo apt-get install git=1:2.17.0-1ubuntu1
apt-cache policy git-man:amd64
```

Output:

```
git-man:
  Installed: 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.10
  Candidate: 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.10
  Version table:
*** 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.10 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:2.17.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

---

```
sudo apt-get install git-man=1:2.17.0-1ubuntu1
```

Comment: Please properly format the message with code block.

Answer (score 0):

OK. To add more to the soup in previous answers where the directories either aren't owned or are outside the user's home directory, a little bit of [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell), and I'm sure someone can translate this to [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), can add the directories to the safe list.

The below was written on Windows, but on Linux, remove the "-replace '\','/'" as it would break anything with spaces in the path.

```
(ls D:\PowerShell\ParentFolder\ -Directory).FullName -replace '\\','/' | %{git config --global --add safe.directory $_}
```

Answer (score 0):

git config --global --add safe.directory '*' //star meal all

you can create all directory is safe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

We have fixed this issue by fixing the .git/objects permissions. We were actually unable to add files without sudo because of the bad permissions.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this does not seem to be adding anything new here!

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I just copy the message, write *sudo*, and then paste the message. After pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button, the issue has gone.

For example:

```
sudo git config --global --add safe.directory your-path
```

'your-path' = as shown in the message

Comment: This solution works but like I said in my question: I have to run this for every single project in my machine. It shouldn't be like this.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't just copy and sudo-paste a message to without understanding the implications of doing so.