# Unsafe repository owned by someone else, ok, but WHO?

Tags: git

I'm trying to git pull and I'm blocked by this error:

`fatal: unsafe repository ... is owned by someone else)`

I've read CVE-2022-24765 but nothing says how to find out who "someone else" is.

This is a really frustrating error message. It's an alarm that doesn't tell you any crucial information and instead just tells you how to disable the alarm.

Comment: Suppose the path is `/foo/bar`. Try `ls -l /foo`. It prints the files and directories under `/foo` with more information which includes the owner name (the 3rd column).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal: unsafe repository ('/home/repon' is owned by someone else)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71901632/fatal-unsafe-repository-home-repon-is-owned-by-someone-else)

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay , `ls -l` got me the information I needed.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of [CVE-2022-24765](https://github.blog/2022-04-12-git-security-vulnerability-announced/)

> a malicious actor could create a `.git` directory in a shared location above a victim’s current working directory.
> On Windows, for example, an attacker could create `C:\.git\config`, which would cause all git invocations that occur *outside* a repository to read its configured values.

[`safe.txt` adds](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1ac7422e39b0043250b026f9988d0da24cb2cb58/Documentation/config/safe.txt):

> By default, Git will refuse to even parse a Git config of a repository owned by someone else, let alone run its hooks, and this config setting allows users to specify exceptions, e.g. for intentionally shared repositories

So the "someone else" is: anyone having access to your computer, and in a folder which is not explicitly listed as "safe".

More details in [commit 8959555](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8959555cee7ec045958f9b6dd62e541affb7e7d9):

> It poses a security risk to search for a git directory outside of the directories owned by the current user.
>
> For example, it is common e.g. in computer pools of educational institutes to have a "scratch" space: a mounted disk with plenty of space that is regularly swiped where any authenticated user can create a directory to do their work.
> Merely navigating to such a space with a
> Git-enabled `PS1` when there is a maliciously-crafted `/scratch/.git/`
> can lead to a compromised account.
>
> The same holds true in multi-user setups running Windows, as `C:\` is writable to every authenticated user by default.
>
> To plug this vulnerability, we stop Git from accepting top-level directories owned by someone other than the current user. We avoid looking at the ownership of each and every directory between the current and the top-level one (if there are any between) to avoid introducing a performance bottleneck.
>
> This new default behavior is obviously incompatible with the concept of shared repositories, where we expect the top-level directory to be owned by only one of its legitimate users. To re-enable that use case, we add support for adding exceptions from the new default behavior via the config setting `safe.directory`.

Answer (score 0):

OP here, based on @ElpieKay suggestion I tried `ls -l` in a few directories and discovered that I had committed some files while logged into my Github work account.