# Why can't I use "./" in "git config --global --add safe.directory ./"?

Tags: git

When running

```
git config --global --add safe.directory (directory_path)
```

I found that `(directory_path)` cannot be set to `./`

Why? Are there any limitations?

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: Maybe this is a limitation of your shell. Have you tried placing the value within quotes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add directory recursively on git safe.directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71855882/how-to-add-directory-recursively-on-git-safe-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(pwd)` instead of `./` and it'll work just fine. pwd returns current working directory as full path

The full command will be `git config --global --add safe.directory $(pwd)`