# Error updating changes: unsafe repository ... is owned by someone else

Tags: git, android-studio, security, version-control, repository

Recently when I open git projects in Android Studio, I receive this error :

```
Error updating changes: Unsafe repository (`project name` is owned by someone else). To add an exception to this directory, call : git config --global --add safe.directory ...
```

I know using command line mentioned I can get rid of this, but isn't there any automatic solution?

I have lots of projects and every now and then I face this!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check your Git version first:

```
git version
```

If it is the recent 2.35.2 or 2.36, you need to set the [`safe.directory` setting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/#Documentation/git-config.txt-safedirectory), because of [CVE-2022-24765](https://github.blog/2022-04-12-git-security-vulnerability-announced/).

```
git config --global --add safe.directory 'Path/To/Repo'
```

Or you [can disable it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71904131/6309), but make sure you understand [why it is there in the first place](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8959555cee7ec045958f9b6dd62e541affb7e7d9).

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: With what version of Git? Can you describe your use case in a separate question?

Comment: I have a workspace directory in WSL, accessing it from IntelliJ on Windows. Do I have to add that for every single Git repository now or can I point to the parent?

Comment: @MarianKlühspies I haven't tested it but you can try a global config with the parent folder to those repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **add SSH into your desktop/laptop**.

To create a new SSH **follow**
[GitHub Link to Generate New SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

Once you have added the SSH onto your desktop/laptop, **open the .pub file in VS Code or NotePad++**. Copy the entire key and paste it in the **Key column** in your **GitHub** account.

Once you have completed all the steps don't forget to **restart the Android Studio**. I have tried and tested the proceducre it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my issue by deleting the gitignore file, misc and vcs.xml file of the current project.