# Everything runs fine, but at the end the following error comes

Tags: linux, gitlab, cicd

```
Code:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Exit immediately if command returns bad exit code
set -e

ENABLED_SLACK_REFS=(develop qa main prod)
export CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR=$(git log --format="%an" -n1)
export CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE=$(git log --format="%B" -n1)
export CI_COMMIT_URL="${CI_PROJECT_URL}/commit/${CI_COMMIT_SHA}"

main() {
    if fn_exists $1; then
        ${1}
    else
        echo "Function $1 doesn't exist" && exit 1
    fi
}

#------------------------------------------
# Job Tasks
#------------------------------------------

function build_docker_for_pipeline() {
    # Pull latest version of image for branch / tag, for caching purposes (speed up the build)
    # docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_BRANCH_SLUG} || true
    # Build and tag with this pipeline ID so we can use it later, in test & release & deploy
    docker build --build-arg CI=${CI} -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID} .
    # docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}
}

function lint() {
    # docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
    docker run --rm -e CI=${CI} ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID} lint
}

function test() {
    # Pull image built within this pipeline previously
    docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
    # Run npm test, via entrypoint.sh test action and generate coverage
    mkdir coverage && docker run --rm -e CI=${CI} \
      --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/coverage,target=/app/coverage \
      ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID} test --coverage
}

function security() {
    # Pull image built within this pipeline previously
    docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
    # Audit our dependencies for security vulnerabilities
    docker run --rm -e CI=${CI} ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID} yarn audit
}

function release_docker_for_branch() {
    # Pull image built in this pipeline
    docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
    # Tag as latest image for branch / tag
    docker tag ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID} ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_BRANCH_SLUG}
    # Push to GitLab Container Registry
    docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}
}

function deploy() {
    # Run npm build, setting REACT_APP_* env variables
    export REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME:-dev}
    export REACT_APP_SENTRY_VERSION="${CI_PROJECT_NAME}@$(jq -r '.version' package.json)-${CI_JOB_ID}"
    echo $REACT_APP_SENTRY_VERSION
    echo "Building app via Docker, injecting following environment variables:"
    get_react_env_vars_raw_names
    docker run --rm -v source=/home/halo-solutions-ltd/actions-runner/_work/halo-web/halo-web/,target=/app \
      $(get_react_env_vars_for_docker) \
      ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_PIPELINE_ID} build
    # create_sentry_release
    # Set up required environment variables for deployment
    export_deploy_ci_variables
    aws configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 20
    # Sync build output with what is currently deployed
    # This also deletes files in bucket that aren't present in build output (cleans old releases)
    # Set a blanket cache policy to cache for up to 12hrs - used for versioned static assets
    aws s3 sync build s3://${CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET} --delete --cache-control "public,max-age=43200" --exclude "*.map"
    # Disable caching for specific files. In particular, ones that reference versioned assets
    # This means we can cache bust our versioned assets!
    export CACHE_DISABLED_PARAMS="--metadata-directive REPLACE --cache-control max-age=0,no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate --acl public-read"
    aws s3 cp s3://${CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET}/service-worker.js s3://${CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET}/service-worker.js --content-type application/javascript ${CACHE_DISABLED_PARAMS}
    aws s3 cp s3://${CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET}/index.html s3://${CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET}/index.html --content-type text/html ${CACHE_DISABLED_PARAMS}
    aws s3 cp s3://${CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET}/manifest.json s3://${CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET}/manifest.json --content-type application/json ${CACHE_DISABLED_PARAMS}
    aws s3 cp s3://${CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET}/asset-manifest.json s3://${CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET}/asset-manifest.json --content-type application/json ${CACHE_DISABLED_PARAMS}
    # finalize_sentry_release
}

function deploy_qa_if_updated() {
    last_qa_release=$(AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAJ6355LQD3QU4IK3A AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=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 \
        aws dynamodb get-item --table-name gitlab-react-qa-releases --key "{\"ProjectId\": {\"N\": \"${CI_PROJECT_ID}\"}}" \
        --output text --query "Item.[LastReleaseSha.S,LastReleaseTimestamp.N]"
    )
    echo "Last QA Release: ${last_qa_release}"
    # If first QA release
    if [ "${last_qa_release}" = "None" ]; then
        deploy && update_last_qa_release && deploy_success_slack
        return 0
    fi
    last_qa_release_sha=$(echo "${last_qa_release}" | awk '{print $1}')
    last_qa_release_timestamp=$(echo "${last_qa_release}" | awk '{print $2}')
    # If current commit is same as last release, or last release isn't in history (not sure how)
    if [ "${CI_COMMIT_SHA}" = "${last_qa_release_sha}" ] || ! git merge-base --is-ancestor ${last_qa_release_sha} HEAD; then
        no_qa_updates_slack ${last_qa_release_sha} ${last_qa_release_timestamp}
        return 0
    fi
    # If last release occurred previously in branch
    deploy && update_last_qa_release && deploy_success_slack
    return 0
}

function update_last_qa_release() {
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1 AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAJ6355LQD3QU4IK3A AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=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 \
        aws dynamodb put-item --table-name gitlab-react-qa-releases --item \
        "{\
            \"ProjectId\": {\"N\": \"${CI_PROJECT_ID}\"}, \
            \"LastReleaseSha\": {\"S\": \"${CI_COMMIT_SHA}\"}, \
            \"LastReleaseTimestamp\": {\"N\": \"$(date +%s)\"} \
        }"
}

#------------------------------------------
# Slack functions
#------------------------------------------

function slack_enabled_for_ref() {
    local ref
    ref=${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:-none}
    echo "${ENABLED_SLACK_REFS[*]}" | grep -F -q -w "$ref";
}

function deploy_success_slack() {
    if [ ! -z ${CI_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL+x} ] && slack_enabled_for_ref; then
        local text attachments
        export_deploy_ci_variables
        text="Successful deployment of <${CI_PIPELINE_URL}|${CI_PROJECT_NAME}> to <${CF_URL}|${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}>"
        attachments="{\"fallback\":\"${text}\",\"color\":\"good\", \"text\": \"${text}\",\
            \"fields\": [\
                {\"title\": \"Git Commit\", \"value\": \"${CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE}\"},\
                {\"title\": \"Git Author\", \"value\": \"${CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR}\"}\
            ],\
            \"actions\": [\
                {\"type\": \"button\", \"text\": \"View Pipeline\", \"style\": \"primary\", \"url\": \"${CI_PIPELINE_URL}\"}\
            ]\
        }"

        curl -s -X POST --data-urlencode \
        "payload={\"channel\": \"${CI_SLACK_CHANNEL}\", \"username\": \"React GitLab CICD\",\
        \"attachments\": [${attachments}], \"icon_emoji\": \":reactjs:\" }" \
        "${CI_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}"
    fi
}

function deploy_failure_slack() {
    if [ ! -z ${CI_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL+x} ] && slack_enabled_for_ref; then
        local text attachments
        text="Failed to deploy <${CI_PIPELINE_URL}|${CI_PROJECT_NAME}> to ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}"
        attachments="{\"fallback\":\"${text}\",\"color\":\"danger\", \"text\": \"${text}\",\
            \"fields\": [\
                {\"title\": \"Git Commit\", \"value\": \"${CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE}\"},\
                {\"title\": \"Git Author\", \"value\": \"${CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR}\"}\
            ],\
            \"actions\": [\
                {\"type\": \"button\", \"text\": \"View Pipeline\", \"style\": \"primary\", \"url\": \"${CI_PIPELINE_URL}\"}\
            ]\
        }"

        curl -s -X POST --data-urlencode \
        "payload={\"channel\": \"${CI_SLACK_CHANNEL}\", \"username\": \"React GitLab CICD\",\
        \"attachments\": [${attachments}], \"icon_emoji\": \":reactjs:\" }" \
        "${CI_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}"
    fi
}

function job_failure_slack() {
    if [ ! -z ${CI_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL+x} ] && slack_enabled_for_ref; then
        local text attachments
        text="The ${CI_JOB_NAME} job failed in the <${CI_PIPELINE_URL}|${CI_PROJECT_NAME}> pipeline."
        attachments="{\"fallback\":\"${text}\",\"color\":\"danger\", \"text\": \"${text}\",\
            \"fields\": [\
                {\"title\": \"Git Author\", \"value\": \"${CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR}\", \"short\": true},\
                {\"title\": \"Git Branch\", \"value\": \"${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}\", \"short\": true}\
            ],\
            \"actions\": [\
                {\"type\": \"button\", \"text\": \"View Pipeline\", \"style\": \"primary\", \"url\": \"${CI_PIPELINE_URL}\"}\
            ]\
        }"

        curl -s -X POST --data-urlencode \
        "payload={\"channel\": \"${CI_SLACK_CHANNEL}\", \"username\": \"React GitLab CICD\",\
        \"attachments\": [${attachments}], \"icon_emoji\": \":reactjs:\" }" \
        "${CI_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}"
    fi
}

function no_qa_updates_slack() {
    # $1 = Last Release Sha, $2 = Last Release Timestamp
    if [ ! -z ${CI_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL+x} ] && slack_enabled_for_ref; then
        local text attachments
        text="No unreleased changes found to make a scheduled QA release. The last release was at $(date --date="@$2" "+%a %d %b %T UTC")"
        attachments="{\"fallback\":\"${text}\",\"color\":\"good\", \"text\": \"${text}\",\
            \"fields\": [\
                {\"title\": \"Last Commit Message\", \"value\": \"$(git show -s --format=%B $1)\"},\
                {\"title\": \"Last Commit Hash\", \"value\": \"<${CI_PROJECT_URL}/commit/$1|$(git rev-parse --short $1)>\"}\
            ]\
        }"

        curl -s -X POST --data-urlencode \
        "payload={\"channel\": \"${CI_SLACK_CHANNEL}\", \"username\": \"React GitLab CICD\",\
        \"attachments\": [${attachments}], \"icon_emoji\": \":reactjs:\" }" \
        "${CI_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}"
    fi
}

#------------------------------------------
# utils
#------------------------------------------

# Create a Sentry release and upload source maps
function create_sentry_release() {
    export SENTRY_URL="${SENTRY_URL:-https://sentry.io}"
    export SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN="${SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN}"
    export SENTRY_ORG="${SENTRY_ORG:-halo-solutions-ltd}"
    export SENTRY_PROJECT="${SENTRY_PROJECT:-$CI_PROJECT_NAME}"
    export SENTRY_DISABLE_UPDATE_CHECK="true"
    export SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL="info"
    sentry-cli releases new $REACT_APP_SENTRY_VERSION
    #TODO: sentry-cli releases set-commits --auto $REACT_APP_SENTRY_VERSION
    sentry-cli releases files $REACT_APP_SENTRY_VERSION upload-sourcemaps -x .js -x .map --validate --rewrite --url-prefix '~/static/js/' ./build/static/js/
}

# Finalize a Sentry release (call once deployed)
function finalize_sentry_release() {
    sentry-cli releases finalize $REACT_APP_SENTRY_VERSION
}

# Get the REACT_APP env vars for this build.
# That is, env vars beginning with REACT_APP_ or <ENV>_REACT_APP_
function get_react_env_vars() {
    env | egrep "(^REACT_APP_)|(^${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_REACT_APP_)"
}

# Get the raw names of REACT_APP env vars we will be injecting into build
# That is, names of all env vars starting with REACT_APP_ or <ENV>_REACT_APP_
function get_react_env_vars_raw_names() {
    get_react_env_vars | egrep -oh "^(.*=)*" | cut -d '=' -f 1
}

# Get react env vars in format ready to pass to Docker as env variables
# all <ENV>_REACT_APP_ vars renamed to REACT_APP_ format
# Prepended with -e so it can be passed to Docker build as env vars
function get_react_env_vars_for_docker() {
    get_react_env_vars | sed "s/^${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_REACT_APP/REACT_APP/" \
    | sed "s/^/-e /"
}

# Export CI variables needed for deployment
function export_deploy_ci_variables() {
    export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(A=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_CI_DEPLOY_ACCESS_KEY_ID; echo ${!A})
    export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(A=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_CI_DEPLOY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY; echo ${!A})
    export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=$(A=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_CI_DEPLOY_REGION; echo ${!A})
    export CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET=$(S3=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET; echo ${!S3})
    export CI_CF_DISTRIBUTION=$(CFD=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_CI_CF_DISTRIBUTION; echo ${!CFD})
    export CF_URL=$(aws cloudfront get-distribution --id ${CI_CF_DISTRIBUTION} \
        --query "Distribution.[DomainName, DistributionConfig.Aliases.Items[0]]" \
        --output text | awk '{if($2 == "None"){print "http://"$1} else {print "http://"$2}}')
}

function fn_exists() {
  # appended double quote is an ugly trick to make sure we do get a string -- if $1 is not a known command, type does not output anything
  [ `type -t $1`"" == 'function' ]
}

main "$@"
```

Now here is the working flow of github:

```
name: halo solutions web-admin deployment

# Modified for Halo post HHL handover 21/05/22 ML

# develop -> dev
# qa -> qa
# main -> uat
# prod -> prod/live

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/*
      - issue/*
      - develop
      - qa
      - main
      - prod
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop
      - qa
      - main
      - prod
env: 
  PROJECT: halo-web
  CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: halo-solutions-ltd/halo-web
  CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME: DEV
  CI_SLACK_CHANNEL: ${{ secrets.CI_SLACK_CHANNEL }}
  CI_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ${{ secrets.CI_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}
  CI_JOB_ID: ${{ github.run_id }}
  CI_PIPELINE_ID: ${{ github.run_id }}

jobs:
  lint_test_build_release:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    container: 
      image: ghcr.io/halo-solutions-ltd/docker-aws:latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo content
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build
        uses: ./.github/common/build
        with:
          command: "./ci build_docker_for_pipeline || { ./ci job_failure_slack; exit 1; }"
      # TODO : Need to implement composite action so we can avoid repeating the code
      - name: Dev deploy
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop'
        run: |
          export CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g')
          export CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME=DEV
          export DEV_REACT_APP_ENV_NAME=${{ secrets.DEV_REACT_APP_ENV_NAME }}
          export DEV_REACT_APP_JS_KEY=${{ secrets.DEV_REACT_APP_JS_KEY }}
          export DEV_REACT_APP_KEY=${{ secrets.DEV_REACT_APP_KEY }}
          export DEV_REACT_APP_PARSE_SERVER=${{ secrets.DEV_REACT_APP_PARSE_SERVER }}
          export DEV_REACT_APP_SERVER=${{ secrets.DEV_REACT_APP_SERVER }}
          export DEV_CI_DEPLOY_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ secrets.DEV_CI_DEPLOY_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          export DEV_CI_DEPLOY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ secrets.DEV_CI_DEPLOY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          export DEV_CI_DEPLOY_REGION=${{ secrets.DEV_CI_DEPLOY_REGION }}
          export DEV_CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET=${{ secrets.DEV_CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET }}
          export DEV_CI_CF_DISTRIBUTION=${{ secrets.DEV_CI_CF_DISTRIBUTION }}
          ./ci deploy && ./ci deploy_success_slack || { ./ci deploy_failure_slack; exit 1; }
      
      - name: QA deploy
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/qa'
        run: |
          export CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g')
          export CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME=QA
          export QA_REACT_APP_ENV_NAME=${{ secrets.QA_REACT_APP_ENV_NAME }}
          export QA_REACT_APP_JS_KEY=${{ secrets.QA_REACT_APP_JS_KEY }}
          export QA_REACT_APP_KEY=${{ secrets.QA_REACT_APP_KEY }}
          export QA_REACT_APP_PARSE_SERVER=${{ secrets.QA_REACT_APP_PARSE_SERVER }}
          export QA_REACT_APP_SERVER=${{ secrets.QA_REACT_APP_SERVER }}
          export QA_CI_DEPLOY_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ secrets.QA_CI_DEPLOY_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          export QA_CI_DEPLOY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ secrets.QA_CI_DEPLOY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          export QA_CI_DEPLOY_REGION=${{ secrets.QA_CI_DEPLOY_REGION }}
          export QA_CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET=${{ secrets.QA_CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET }}
          export QA_CI_CF_DISTRIBUTION=${{ secrets.QA_CI_CF_DISTRIBUTION }}
          ./ci deploy && ./ci deploy_success_slack || { ./ci deploy_failure_slack; exit 1; }
      
      - name: UAT deploy
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
        run: |
          export CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g')
          export CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME=UAT
          export UAT_REACT_APP_ENV_NAME=${{ secrets.UAT_REACT_APP_ENV_NAME }}
          export UAT_REACT_APP_JS_KEY=${{ secrets.UAT_REACT_APP_JS_KEY }}
          export UAT_REACT_APP_KEY=${{ secrets.UAT_REACT_APP_KEY }}
          export UAT_REACT_APP_PARSE_SERVER=${{ secrets.UAT_REACT_APP_PARSE_SERVER }}
          export UAT_REACT_APP_SERVER=${{ secrets.UAT_REACT_APP_SERVER }}
          export UAT_CI_DEPLOY_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ secrets.UAT_CI_DEPLOY_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          export UAT_CI_DEPLOY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ secrets.UAT_CI_DEPLOY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          export UAT_CI_DEPLOY_REGION=${{ secrets.UAT_CI_DEPLOY_REGION }}
          export UAT_CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET=${{ secrets.UAT_CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET }}
          export UAT_CI_CF_DISTRIBUTION=${{ secrets.UAT_CI_CF_DISTRIBUTION }}
          ./ci deploy && ./ci deploy_success_slack || { ./ci deploy_failure_slack; exit 1; }

      - name: LIVE deploy
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/prod'
        run: |
          export CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g')
          export CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME=LIVE
          export LIVE_REACT_APP_ENV_NAME=${{ secrets.LIVE_REACT_APP_ENV_NAME }}
          export LIVE_REACT_APP_KEY=${{ secrets.LIVE_REACT_APP_KEY }}
          export LIVE_REACT_APP_PARSE_SERVER=${{ secrets.LIVE_REACT_APP_PARSE_SERVER }}
          export LIVE_REACT_APP_SERVER=${{ secrets.LIVE_REACT_APP_SERVER }}
          export LIVE_CI_DEPLOY_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ secrets.LIVE_CI_DEPLOY_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          export LIVE_CI_DEPLOY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ secrets.LIVE_CI_DEPLOY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          export LIVE_CI_DEPLOY_REGION=${{ secrets.LIVE_CI_DEPLOY_REGION }}
          export LIVE_CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET=${{ secrets.LIVE_CI_DEPLOY_BUCKET }}
          export LIVE_CI_CF_DISTRIBUTION=${{ secrets.LIVE_CI_CF_DISTRIBUTION }}
          ./ci deploy && ./ci deploy_success_slack || { ./ci deploy_failure_slack; exit 1; }
```

These are errors:

Done in 86.82s.

The user-provided path build does not exist.

fatal: unsafe repository ('/__w/halo-web/halo-web' is owned by someone else)

To add an exception for this directory, call:

git config --global --add safe.directory /__w/halo-web/halo-web

fatal: unsafe repository ('/__w/halo-web/halo-web' is owned by someone else)

To add an exception for this directory, call:

git config --global --add safe.directory /__w/halo-web/halo-web

Error: Process completed with exit code 3.

This is the thing which is very all ok but providing some type of errors and make some errors. Have any suggestions related to this..?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/71849415/1216776

Answer (score 0):

The [GitLab Runner 16.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/08/22/gitlab-16-3-released/#gitlab-runner-163) (August 2023) should address that with the completion of [`gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` issue 29022](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/29022)

> The change made in recent Git releases to address [CVE-2022-24765](https://github.blog/2022-04-12-git-security-vulnerability-announced/) now disallows use of any git commands under the project clone directory if the container runs as a non-root user:
> Example scenario:
>
> 1. Job runs helper image for clone operation under the build directory as user X
> 2. Job initiates build image container and the job script after successful clone
> 3. Build image container runs as a different user Y
> 4. Build script attempts to clone another repository via `git clone` as a dependency it requires, with its destination somewhere under the working directory (project clone directory)
>
> The step (4) used to pass prior to use of changes introduced in Git 2.35.2.
> Now, the step (4) may fail with the following, and manual [safe directory `.gitconfig` overrides](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.35.2#Documentation/git-config.txt-safedirectory) are required to workaround it:
>
> ```
> fatal: unsafe repository ('/builds/project/group' is owned by someone else)
> ```
>
> Note: The clones are performed by default as root or ContainerAdmin user through GitLab Runner's default helper images.
>
> #### Proposal
>
> - Add new Runner option `SetSafeDirectoryCheckout`
> - Option should be enabled by default in environments where we're okay to modify global git options.
> - Option will be available for other executors, but will be disabled by default.
> - When enabled, we run:
>
>   ```
>   git config --global --add safe.directory /builds/group/project
>   ```

See also [GitLab Runner Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner), and [GitLab Runner CHANGELOG](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/16-3-stable/CHANGELOG.md).