# Git collaboration on Windows 10 network shared folder not working

Tags: git, github

We work in some files that are placed in network share, more than one person can modify the same file,  but when trying to push updates to github, we get error:

> fatal: unsafe repository ('XXXX' is owned by someone else)

I have tried to update configuration of repo and mark it as safe directory but not working also

```
git config --global --add safe.directory d:\reponame
```

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't everyone just clone the git repo locally?  That's the standard thing to do.  If it's because the repo itself is to big, Google for "git virtual file system".

Comment: @selbie, the files in shared network are used by a production application. if everyone has it's own repo then application will not be able to read modifications to have been done to files. what do think on this case ?

Comment: @AhmSf , Then do like this : `1. Have local clone in dev machines` as @selbie mentioned. `2. Push the changes to a branch and do merge to master as a git admin`  Use a single branch (say master). `3. clone same repo with branch master to the common location`. and  `4. Just keep fetch and reset to master` Do not try to push from common location.

Comment: Here's a well defined answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71850261/2086966